# NotificationCompat.Builder() not accepting Channel Id as argument

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.1-oreo, notification-channel

I know this question has been asked several times before. But none of the solutions worked for me. That's why I would like to ask the question again. The following line only accepts `NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)  // Getting error
```

I have fulfilled:

- importing `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`
- My support libraries version is above 25

  `implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: '27.1.1`'
- Compile & Target sdk is above 25

  `android {
      compileSdkVersion(27)
      buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
      flavorDimensions 'default'
      dataBinding {
          enabled = true
  }
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId('something')
      minSdkVersion(16)
      targetSdkVersion(27)
      versionCode(1)
      versionName('1.0.0')
     testInstrumentationRunner('android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner')
      multiDexEnabled true
   }`

  But still getting the error. What should I do to fix this? Please help.

Comment: send your error log

Comment: I am getting error in compile time. `Builder(context) cannot be applied to Builder(context, java.lang.String)`

Comment: Which API level are you running this on? Also, shouldn't your targetSdkVersion be 27 in order to match the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion?

Comment: first you must send your compile error too. second i thing you have another Builder that make error

Comment: I've tried setting targetSDK version to 27. Didn't work. :(

Comment: Try my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

On Android 8.0 (Oreo) you must have something called as a `NotificationChannel` So try the below implementation:

**Step1:** Create Notification Channel

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

**Finally:** Then your Notification:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) // notification icon
                .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
                .setContentText("Hello word") // message for notification
                .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RecorderActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Please compare this with Yours and see if it works

Try this, Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can add notification channel only for versions greater than or equal 26, the versions below android 8.0 doesn't support notification channel. My suggestion would be using following codes:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
           { 
             NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID) 
           }

    else NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your gradle dependencies.
I was also not getting the the setChannelId method or the arguments.
But as it came in the updated version of the support library. You will find it.
Try using

> `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`

Answer (score -1):

First create notification channel and notification passing channel ID.

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context
                     .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  buildNotificationChannel(manager,String <Channel_ID>,String description);
```

Create Notification channel.

```
 public void buildNotificationChannel(NotificationManager manager, String channelID, 
       String description) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
             if (manager.getNotificationChannel(channelID) == null) {
               NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, 
               description,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
               channel.setDescription(description);
               manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
           }
      }
  }
```

Create Notification passing argument channel ID

```
     Notification notification = new 
     NotificationCompat.Builder(context,<Channel_ID>)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Title goes here.")
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setContentText("Content Text").build();
        notificationManager.notify(ID,notification);
```

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder()` not accepting 2nd argument.